# Is it possible to limit how much CPU a virtual machine can use with VMWare Player?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, cpu, vmware-player

Is it possible to limit how much CPU a virtual machine can use with VMWare Player?

I use VMWare to run a Windows XP virtual machine. I want to keep it on in the background all the time.

The real computer runs Windows 7 and is sometimes a little bit short of memory. That's why I want to check if I can throttle the VM down to the bare minimum to keep it running in the background constantly without interfering too much.

Answer (score 2):

You can check CPU management (of VM) in Control Panel -> Power options -> Change plan settings -> Change advanced power settings -> Processor power management -> Maximum Power State.

Set it in percent value: i.e. you have 1 CPU 1 Core 4.0Ghz within you VM and you want to spent maximum 2.0Ghz - then set 50%.

But pay attention to your VM settings - Check out how many processors and cores is in use - via "VM settings-CPU options" (something like that).

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple cores in the machine (Say 4 core machine), then you can assign 1 core to the VM and that will limit the CPU usage.

But if you do not then as the previous answer pointed out, you will have to limit VMWare itself to CPU usage which is not recommended to do.

Note that this does not limit portions on a single core. Rather, this limits the VM to one core instead.

Answer (score -2):

**of course....it is possible.
reducing the vmware cpu usage may damage your logical machine performance.**

take a look to this article:
http://tech-nets.blogspot.com/2012/12/limit-your-application-cpu-usage.html